# How to find controls in a form which has deep FormArray in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a survey, which has many questions. and each questions has many answers. How could I build this form using Angular Reactive form?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" [formGroup]="surveyForm">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Survey</h2>
    </div>
<div formArrayName="questions">    
@for (question of sheet.questions; track question;let i=$index) {
    <div class="row question-box" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input type="text" [value]="question.id" formControlName="questionId" />
        {{i+1}}. {{question.text}}
        <div class="answers-box" formArrayName="choices">
            @if(question.type=="RadioButton"){
                @for(answer of question.answers;track answer;let j=$index){
                    <div class="answer" [formGroupName]="j">
                        <label>
                            {{j+1}}. <input type="radio" formControlName="answer"
                             [value]="answer.value" (change)="onRadioChange($event)"> <span>{{answer.text}}</span>
                        </label>       
                    </div>
                }
            }@else if (question.type=="Number") {
                @for(answer of question.answers;track answer;let j=$index){
                    <div class="answer"  [formGroupName]="j">
                        <input type="number" [value]="answer.value"/>
                    </div>
                }
            }

        </div>
       
    </div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

And ts:

```
surveyForm!: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void{
    this.surveyForm = new FormGroup({
      questions: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.initQuestions(),
      ])
    });
}
initQuestions(){
  return new FormGroup({
    questionId: new FormControl(''),
    choices: new FormArray([
      this.initChoice(),
    ])
  });
}
initChoice(){
  return new FormGroup({
    answer: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

And error:

- Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 1'
- Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 1 -> questionId'
- Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 1 -> choices'
- Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> 1 -> choices -> 0'

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example - your ts code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Some generals ideas to mannage FormArrays and FormGroups

1. NEVER,NEVER,NEVER mix formControlName with value
2. A FormArray can be a FormArray of FormGroups or a FormArray of
   FormControls. If only need an array simple use a FromArray of FormControls, if you need an array of object you use a FromArray of FromGroups
3. When you use a FormArray you use a getter, when use a formArray
   inside a FormArray you use a function that need an index and return
   the formArray

   ```
   get questions() {
     return (this.surveyForm.get('questions') as FormArray);
   }
   //and
   getChoices(index:number)
   {
      return this.questionGroups.at(index) as FormArray
   }
   ```
4. You should iterate always about FormArray.controls, not over any
   array

   ```
   //not use
   @for (question of sheet.questions; track question;let i=$index) {..}
   //else
   @for (group of questions.controls; track i;let i=$index) {
          I'm the question: {{question[i]}}
   }
   ```
5. When we create the formGroup in a ngOnInit, to avoid initial errors
   you can use

   ```
   <form *ngIf="surveyForm" [formGroup]="surveyForm">
   ...
   </form>
   ```
6. Sometimes, it's util to check use

   ```
   <pre>
   {{surveyForm.value|json}}
   </pre>
   ```
7. You can use "dot" notation with the method get to "reach" any
   FormControl,

   ```
   e.g.
   i=0;
   j=3;
   const control=surveyForm.get('questions.'+i+'.choices.'+j+'.answer')
   ```